# Authenticate automatically by IP Address in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I would like to automatically authenticate users who visit a protected area in TYPO3 from a specific IP-address. The login page should be skipped. It should be possible to directly access URLs in protected areas without being redirected to the login page.

I have tested the extension "aoe_ipauth". Unfortunately, "direct" linking of content pages is not possible here.

Does anyone have an idea? Possibly by adapting a TYPO3 middleware?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're on the right track but trying to tackle the wrong problem. The extension you're talking about isn't able to login directly after a link to a page, because that's not the function of an authentication service.

Take a look at the FE login process and redirects to get this to properly work. You'll need to set a couple of things

```
# https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#typolinklinkaccessrestrictedpages
# If set, typolinks pointing to access restricted pages will still link to the page even though the page cannot be accessed. 
# If the value of this setting is an integer it will be interpreted as a page id to which the link will be directed.
config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages = id_to_your_login_page
```

This will set a redirect to your login page when a user is not logged in yet.
You can use the *aoe_ipauth* to login the user and redirect the user back to where they came from with either the Redirect Mode https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-felogin/master/en-us/LoginMechanism/RedirectModes/Index.html#defined-by-get-post-vars or https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-felogin/master/en-us/LoginMechanism/RedirectModes/Index.html#defined-by-referrer